# conditional htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

lets say i have the following GET variables available:

> state
>
> city
>
> bedrooms
>
> bathrooms
>
> type
>
> price

now i want them to come out like this:

mysite.com/state/city/#-bedrooms/#-bathrooms/type/price

however, i want this to work so that if one of these variables are not there, it will still work

i.e.:

mysite.com/state/city/#-bedrooms

or:

mysite.com/state/#-bedrooms/price

how do i do this?

Comment: You can use actual GET variables.  `mysite.com?state=XX&city=YYY&...`

Comment: Is state mandatory or even that is optional? And what will be URI in that case?

Comment: This should probably be something for PHP to deal (not .htaccess).

Comment: Be careful with this approach, you'll be creating pages that have the same content but different URLs and might get penalized by Google for having duplicate content. I'd suggest specifying a [canonical URL](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139066) for each of these pages to ensure you don't get hurt by it.

Comment: they wont have the same content though. they will have content relevant to what GET variables are set, and what those variables are set to.

Comment: Use a common prefix such as `/search/` and Rewrite anything that starts with `/search/` to one PHP script. Use `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to extract the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make parts of a regex optional using the `?` quantifier.

```
            # state   city       bedrooms              bathrooms
RewriteRule ^(\w+)(?:/(\w+))?(?:/(\d+)-bedrooms)?(?:/(\d+)-bathrooms)?$
            script.php?state=$1&city=$2&bedrooms=$3&bathrooms=$4
# add further (?:(\d+)-placeholders)? for the other optional parts
```

This will however rewrite to empty variables if a subpattern is not matched.

So maybe you should rather define a *list* of RewriteRules with varying specificness:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\d+)-bedrooms$ scr?state=$1&bed=$2
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)-bedrooms$ scr?state=$1&city=$2&bed=$3
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to do right in your code:

```
#.htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

You can use whatever logic you want to process the request URI:

```
#index.php
<?php
$request = explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
$state = array_shift($request);
$city = array_shift($request);
// and so on
```