# Get Originally Requested URL for "View Full Site" Link After Mobile Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I've searched thoroughly for a similar topic and couldn't find one.  Here's hoping someone can help.

=> THE SET-UP:

I'm using an .htaccess mobile redirect that I found in the wild.

The redirect sends visitors on mobile devices from www.MYSITE.com to m.MYSITE.com (a simple .html "splash page").  On this mobile version is a link for visitors to use to continue to the full site:

```
<a href="http://www.MYSITE.com">Visit Full Version</a>
```

=> THE PROBLEM:

A user visits www.MYSITE.com/page from a search engine.  The user is redirected to the mobile splash page at m.MYSITE.com and they click the "Visit Full Version" link.  Instead of being redirected to the full site version of www.MYSITE.com/page, they are sent to www.MYSITE.com.

I need visitors to be able to get back to the originally requested URL (like www.MYSITE.com/page or even www.MYSITE.com/page/post) from the m.MYSITE.com splash page "View Full Version" link.

My .htaccess code is below:

```
# If you're not already on m.YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com,
# and if you're on a mobile device,
# and if you just got here (didn't get here by clicking links on YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.com),
# and if you're not just looking for pictures
# then go to the mobile site instead
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.MYSITE\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.*).MYSITE.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.MYSITE.com [L,R=302]
```

=> THE QUESTION:

What can I work into my .htaccess file and/or mobile index.php to send visitors back to their originally requested URL as the "Visit Full Version" link?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `conditional` .htaccess here.

Pass `parameter` to decide whether you want to see the full site

```
<a href="http://www.MYSITE.com?seeFullSite=YES">Visit Full Version</a>
```

if .htaccess check whether `seeFullSite` param is `set` and value is `YES`. if true, then do not redirect to your mobile site.

Example of conditional .htaccess ::

- [conditional htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326477/conditional-htaccess)
- [Conditional .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876655/conditional-htaccess)